# Efficient way to remove all entries from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Which is the better way to remove all entries from a `mongodb collection`?

```
db.collection.remove({})
```

or

```
db.collection.drop()
```

Comment: there's a difference I believe.. Drop will remove your indexes as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.collection.drop()` will delete to whole collection (very fast) and all indexes on the collection.

`db.collection.remove({})` will delete all entries but the collection and the indexes will still exists.

So there is a difference in both operations. The first one is faster but it will delete more meta information. If you want to ceep them, you should not use it.

Answer (score 4):

**Remove all documents in a collection**

```
db.collection.remove({})
```

Will only remove all the data in the collection but leave any indexes intact. If new documents are added to the collection they will populate the existing indexes.

**Drop collection and all attached indexes**

```
db.collection.drop()
```

Will drop the collection and all indexes. If the collection is recreated then the indexes will also need to be re-created.

From your question, if you only want to remove all the entities from a collection then using `db.collection.remove({})` would be better as that would keep the Collection intact with all indexes still in place.

From a speed perspective, the `drop()` command is faster.

Comment: thanks kevin, but apart from indexes which is faster?